# Cloning a uiview defined in interfacebuilder?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

I have a UIView created in interaface builder that is a subview of a scrollview. the UIView contains a button and a label. I would like to use this view as a cookie cutter so I can generate various instances of this view that are aligned next to each other in the scrollview

I can do this programatically but that means I have to progamatically define the view size and subviews programatically, what I would prefer to do is define one instance of the view in interface builder so I can lay it out and then programatically create copies of this view. The goal is to use interfacebuilder as much as possible for defining layouts to reduce the code that I need to write.

Answer (score 1):

I created a UIView category to handle this.

```
@interface UIView (JLTDeepClone)
- (id)deepClone;
@end

@implementation UIView (JLTDeepClone)
- (id)deepClone
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];

    NSKeyedArchiver  *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self forKey:@"view"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];

    NSKeyedUnarchiver  *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    UIView *result = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    return  result;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Entity Framework it sounds like what you are looking for and should help reduce the lines of code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef

Comment: How does anything with a Microsoft domain have anything to do with this?